# error-page tag not rendering appropriate error page when request comes as forward

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml, ofbiz

I have an application and so web.xml. In web.xml I configured error page as below

```
 <error-page>  
  <error-code>404</error-code>  
  <location>/error/err404.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
```

The above thing works perfectly for a uri that is not exists in web.xml.

```
For Eg:
1. localhost:8080/appName/testServlet (Exists in web.xml)

2. localhost:8080/appName/testServletXXX (Not exists)
```

Both urls work perfectly(first url renders actual page, second url renders err404.jsp) when I enter urls directly on browser.

When I forward the request to uri "testServlet ", it works fine as it exists in web.xml. The problem comes when the uri(testServletXXX) is not exist in web.xml. If uri is not exists in web.xml, it is not rendering err404.jsp instead it is rendering error:

```
 HTTP Status 404 - /appName/xxxx

type Status report

message /appName/xxxx

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

which is from tomcat.

Below is the code for forwarding request.

```
ServletContext scRoot = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContext("/appName");      

        rd = scRoot.getRequestDispatcher("testServlet");

        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Why the error-page is not rendering err404 page for the uri that is not exist in web.xml. It is happening especially in forwarding case. Am not able to figure it out. Did I miss any concept/ logic. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show an example of such an URL (is it absolute or relative ?)

Comment: Thanks for reply Serge, Now I edited the post. Just check it. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it is enough, but the javadoc for ServletContext says : *The pathname must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the current context root* : try to use `"/testServlet"`. Unless you have more than one ServletContext, `ServletContext scRoot = getServletConfig().getServletContext();` should be enough. And you should test that `rd` is not null.

Comment: rd is not null and of course the url I put is "/testServletXXX" only. Still It is not working :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce. If no servlet at all catches the url, `rd` is null, and if `DefaultServer` catches, I get the error page. What is you tomcat version and could you show your web.xml ?

Comment: In your case, are you able to get 404 error page defined in error-page tag even if the request(which is not exist in web.xml) is forwarded?

Comment: No : if no servlet catches the url, rd is null. Please show your web.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I found solution myself. Actually, my application has multiple components and each component treated as a webapp. So, each component has own web.xml. Now, what I am doing is, Am forwarding request from one component to another component. Let us say, forwarding from App1 to App2. I have specified error-page tag info in App2 web.xml only. But not in App1. When I put same error-page tag info in App1 web.xml(From where am forwarding request to App2), then every thing works fine. Thanks Serge Ballesta for trying to help me out. I guess my question is not giving enough info to answer. I am posting answer to help some one who is about to face same situation.